# NextJS app frontpage returns 404 after couple of days of being deployed

Tags: reactjs, deployment, next.js, vercel, sentry

I have a NextJS app that is being deployed to **vercel**. It is quite big and we are working on it daily. We are having this huge problem that I cannot seem to solve, and that is after couple of days (0-7) after deployment the frontpage renders the 404 page, but the rest of the website is working as intented. Most of our pages are SSG and we store our content in headless CMS. In `getStaticProps` we fetch the requested page along with its data and check if it exists. If not then we return `{ notfound: true }`. We are logging the errors to **sentry** and it seems that sentry does not log the errors when the website gets to this state. The error is persistant between users and devices. The only way we have solved the issue temporarly is to redeploy the build. The errors from sentry indicates that the client that we are using to fetch the data responds with an error. But we havent seen a spike in errors since we added the sentry intergration. We have tried to replicate the error on staging environment with no success. The error has now happend 5 times and redeploying has worked each time. What we have done to fix the problem is to go over the page and fix all the client/api errors that we found. We `try/catch` everything and log it to sentry. If anyone has had a similar problem or had to debug this issue what did you do to solve this issue?

edit: GetStaticProps code below

```js
export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps<IProps> = async ({
    previewData,
}) => {
    const prismicClient = createClient({
        previewData: previewData,
        routes: routes,
    })

    try {
        const page = await prismicClient.getSingle<
            PrismicDocumentWithUID<IProps['page']['data']>
        >('homepage', {
            lang: 'is',
        })
        const menu = await getMenu('is', previewData)
        const footer = await getFooter('is', previewData)

        return {
            revalidate: 60,
            props: {
                page: page,
                menu,
                lang: 'is',
                footer,
            },
        }
    } catch (error) {
        captureException(error, {
            tags: {
                page: 'Homepage',
                uid: '/',
                lang: 'is',
            },
        })
        return {
            notFound: true,
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the code (`getStaticProps`) for the page that 404s? Are you using Incremental Static Regeneration?

Comment: @juliomalves Thanks for the reply! Yes I've updated the question to include our getstaticprops, and yes we are using IRS.

Comment: Could be worth adding `revalidate: 60` on the `notFound` return as well. In case it does 404 at some point during revalidation, it can still be regenerated at a later point.

Comment: @juliomalves It looks like this has solved the issue, we have not experienced this issue for more than a week! Thank you very much!